# Compare two properties of the same entity in Where clause in RavenDb

Tags: linq, ravendb

I have the following, a priori, simple query on a RavenDb store:

```
return _session
   .Query<StockKeepingUnit>()
   .Where(x => x.QuantityInStock < x.OrderLevel)
   .ToList()
   .GroupBy(x => x.BrandName);
```

To which RavenDb throws an exception on the Where clause: `Could not understand expression: .Where(x => (x.QuantityInStock < x.OrderLevel))`

I understand that the problem is that I cannot query comparing properties on the same entity, and calling `.ToList()` before the where "works around" the problem, but in an extremely inefficient manner.

What would be the proper way to perform this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the index. That allows you to compute things once at indexing time, then at query time, we can just scan the index.

Comment: Thanks @Ayende, but could you illustrate with a code example?